# Can we use generic list instead of array of objects C#

Tags: c#, arrays, generics, generic-list

```
class Student
{
  public string ID { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

Student[] students = new Student[10];
int j = 0;

for(int i=0; i < 100; i++)
{
  if (some condition)
  {
    student[j].ID = anotherIDlist[i]; //some value from another list;
    student[j].Name = anotherNamelist[i]; //some value from another list;
    j++;
  }
}
```

Here I don't know the array length. Need it dynamic depending on the total conditions are true. Is there any efficient way of doing the same using Generic List? If so, how to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your coding style is reasonable and common, but notice how *imperative* it is. You're saying "go around this loop, mutate this collection, change this variable", building the machine that does what you want.  When given the choice I prefer to code in a *declarative* style, and let the compiler build the machine for me. I would be inclined to write your program like this:

```
var query = from i in Enumerable.Range(0, 100)
            where some_condition
            select new Student() { Id = ids[i], Name = names[i] };
var students = query.ToList();
```

Let the compiler worry about the loops and variables and whatnot; you can concentrate on the semantics rather than the mechanisms.

Answer (score 3):

This is really basic stuff:

```
var students = new List<Student>();

for(int i=0; i < 100; i++)
{
    if (some condition)
    {
        // You can produce the student to add any way you like, e.g.:
        someStudent = new Student { ID = anotherIDlist[i], Name = anotherNamelist[i] };
        students.Add(someStudent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Jon, I implemented your solution but then I saw Eric's and changed my code that way. But still your solution was little simpler :)

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Students> students = new List<Students>;

for(int i=0; i < 100; i++)
{
  if (some condition)
  {
    students.Add(new Student { .ID = anotherIDlist[i], .Name = anotherNamelist[i]));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace

```
Student[] students = new Student[10];
```

with

```
List<Student> students = new List<Student();
```

and the loop with:

```
  if (some condition)
  {
    Student student = new Student();
    student.ID = anotherIDlist[i]; //some value from another list;
    student.Name = anotherNamelist[i]; //some value from another list;
    students.Add(student);
    j++;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes a generic `List<Student>` will work great here.

```
List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
for(int i=0; i < 100; i++)
{
  if (some condition)
  {
    Student s = new Student();
    s.ID = anotherIDlist[i]; //some value from another list;
    s.Name = anotherNamelist[i]; //some value from another list;
    students.Add(s);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a similar syntax :

[ArrayList](http://www.csharpfriends.com/Articles/getArticle.aspx?articleID=56)